# Is there any way to know whether a reader is associated with a command object or not

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have a layer where function `openconnection` `closeconnection` ... are written .
I have a big business logic file which has many `data reader` has used.
My problem is this that the data-readers has not been closed.
So the number of connection at in my `app pool` keep increasing.

Is there any wany to find is there any reader is associated with the commnad and if then in the `closeconnection` function I can check command object and close the reader.

Since we are using `ref-cusor` of oracle to read the data. And as far I know this type of cursor is not managed by oracle.
It is very much difficult for me to check all the bll.

Kindly suggest.

### Edit1:

I have also some confusion about dispose if I dispose the command object weather or not the reader dispose will be called. Or If I dispose the Connection object the reader will be disposed.

Comment: Use `using` statements when you create the readers and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for your response. But can I some how know that a command has a reader or not?

Comment: @SLaks I have also a small question when I dispose the command object will the dispose of reader will be called or not?

Comment: You can see whether the reader is closed or not from the reader object (`reader.IsClosed`). The best approach is to always dispose connection, command, reader objects using `using`

Comment: @krshekhar if you dispose the connection object, surely reader object will be disposed. Similarly, if you dispose command object, the reader will be closed..